# VB 2010 Arrays from TXT file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I need to create program that open text document and add new array for any line from the txt to one string. I try with this code but not work:

```
Dim x As New List(Of String)
Dim o As New IO.StreamReader("c:\*.txt")
For Each a As String In o.ReadToEnd()
     x.Add(a)
Next
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the contents of `x` after the `For Each` loop? We need more information.

Comment: What's wrong with `Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)`?

Comment: `but not work` is a *very* poor description of what you'd like help with

Answer (score 3):

`ReadToEnd()` reads the whole file into one single string, therefore you will not be able to loop over the lines.

Make your life easier and write

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("c:\myfile.txt")
```

This reads all the lines into a string array with one single line of code.

---

Note: Wildcards in the filename won't work!

---

If you still want to use the StreamReader, do it like this:

```
Dim lines = New List(Of String)()
Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\MyFile.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        lines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    End While
End Using
```

The `Using` command takes care of closing the reader automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you. . .

```
    Dim o As New IO.StreamReader("C:\PathTo\File.txt")
    Dim x() As String = o.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar(Convert.ToChar(10) & Convert.ToChar(13)))

    For Each elementX As String In x
        Debug.WriteLine(elementX) ' display text from the file
    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  Dim r As New StreamReader(filename)
  Dim x As New List(Of String)
  TextBox1.Text = ""
  Do While r.Peek > -1
     x.add r.ReadLine
  Loop
  r.Close()
```